# Error: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment , when making an HTTP call in Zapier

Tags: javascript, zapier

I wrote a bit of code to input data into a database based on a form submission, the code works just fine when it lives on my site but I needed it to integrate with zapier. When I run the code I get the error "'NoneType' object does not support item assignment", If I ignore the error and turn on the zap it runs and enters the data properly, but still gets the error and will then turn its self off. I am new to coding in zapier and have ready the help page here https://zapier.com/help/code/ but haven't been able to figure out whats wrong.

```
fetch("www.url.com",
{
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
method: "POST",
body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          "values": {
            "1": inputData.name,
            "2": inputData.title,
            "3": inputData.location,
            "5": inputData.phone,
            "6": inputData.email,
            "7": inputData.facebook,
            "8": inputData.twitter,
            "9": inputData.linkedin,
            "10": inputData.about,
            "11": {
                    "url": inputData.image,
                    "type": "image"
                  }
          }
        }
    )
})
.catch(callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that the error was related to the .catch(callback); and added this bit of code above it and it fixed it

```
.then(function(res) {
return res.json();
})
.then(function(json) {
callback(null, json);
})
```